# .NetCore project loading failed in JetBrains Rider on windows

Tags: c#, msbuild, asp.net-core, .net-core, rider

I have installed the latest version of JetBrains Rider 1 EAP and open .NetCore project with project.json that created by VS2015 , I have loading successfully , but when created new .NetCore web project or add new .NetCore class library with .csproj in old project with project.json that library loading failed

```
Project 'ClassLibrary' load failed: Cannot load the project with the current MSBuild toolset.
Please ensure MSBuild 15.0 is installed.
```

I have also installed the .NetCore SDK and runtime from [microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core)

Comment: You'd better install Visual Studio 2017 Community edition as well, which contains all the dependencies, even if you don't plan to use VS.

Comment: Yes, Rider can't work with msbuild from .net core sdk... only with a visual studio's one

Comment: @DragonFire, you are mistaken, at least for the current EAP build, you can as long as you build the MSbuild from source and have latest Mono.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the MSbuild from source after install the latest Mono.

https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/wiki/Building-Testing-and-Debugging-on-.Net-Core-MSBuild

```
./cibuild.sh --target CoreCLR
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that I needed to install the [build tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017) from VS 2017.

Note that after I did that, I get another error which is detailed here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-6179

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue on Ubuntu, trying to build a .NET Core app.

I found these instructions:
https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/documentation/wiki/Building-Testing-and-Debugging-on-.Net-Core-MSBuild.md

Which basically had me:

- clone msbuild repo locally:

  `git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild`
- build it with "bootstrap = true" mode on:

  `./build.sh /p:CreateBootstrap=true`
- In Rider, point the MsBuild referenced to a "custom" one:

  1. File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Toolset and Build
  2. Under "Use MSBuild version," select "Custom"
  3. Point to the `{cloned msbuild}/artifacts/bin/bootstrap/netcoreapp2.1/MSBuild/MSBuild.dll`
  4. Save

And then Rider was happier :)